# Use Check in a While loop without wasting the calculation

Tags: arbitrary-precision, error-trapping

I am trying to generate and solve a matrix that tends towards being singular using variable arbitrary precision to ensure accuracy. Consider, for example, a matrix with tunable singularity:

```
matrix[n_, prec_] := {{1, 0}, {0, N[1/n, prec]}}
```

We can use a while loop with `Check` to determine the appropriate level of precision needed to avoid a badly conditioned matrix:

```
prec = 1;
While[
 Check[LinearSolve@matrix[10^6, prec], err] === err,
 prec = prec + 1;
 ]
sol = LinearSolve@matrix[10^4, prec]
```

Running this snippet indicates that `prec` must be 8 to avoid a badly conditioned matrix.

This isn't a big deal for this `matrix` function, because it's computationally trivial to generate and solve. However, for larger, more expensive to compute `matrix` functions, it would be nice to not waste the results of the evaluation of `matrix` and the `LinearSolve` used in the `Check`.

Is there a way to avoid that wasted computation? Additionally, is there a better way to do this automatic precision tuning (other than adjusting the step size for the increase in `prec`)?

Comment: Would `Check[sol = LinearSolve@matrix[10^6, prec], err] === err` do what you want?

Comment: @MarcoB Doh! Of course. How did I miss that.

Comment: For the second question, you may be interested in [How can I tell if a matrix is ill-conditioned or singular](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/193144/27951).

Comment: @MarcoB I also want the results from `LinearSolve`, so just running `LinearSolve` and monitoring for the warning is sufficient. But, it's a good idea to use the `"ConditionNumber"` argument to estimate the precision needed. Going to think on that.